# how to write below code in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdata

I am converted below code from swift to objective c:

```
func toPCMBuffer(data: NSData) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {
        let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)  // given NSData audio format
        let PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: UInt32(data.length) / audioFormat.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame)
        PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity
        let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(PCMBuffer.format.channelCount))
        data.getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(channels[0]) , length: data.length)
        return PCMBuffer
    }
```

I converted to objective c:

```
-(AVAudioPCMBuffer*)toPCMBuffer: (NSData*)data {

    AVAudioFormat * audioFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc]initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 sampleRate:8000 channels:1 interleaved:false];
    AVAudioPCMBuffer* PCMBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc]initWithPCMFormat:audioFormat frameCapacity:data.length/audioFormat.streamDescription->mBytesPerFrame];
    PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity;
    float *channels = malloc(PCMBuffer.format.channelCount * sizeof(float)); // remember to free eventually
    memcpy(channels, PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, PCMBuffer.format.channelCount * sizeof(float));
    [data getBytes:channels length:data.length];
    return PCMBuffer;

}
```

but I'm not sure to correct to line code:

```
AVAudioPCMBuffer* PCMBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc]initWithPCMFormat:audioFormat frameCapacity:data.length/audioFormat.streamDescription->mBytesPerFrame];
```

this is the code I not know how to do write `UInt32(data.length)` to objective c

and:

how to convert `UnsafeMutableRawPointer(channels[0])` to objc?

```
[data getBytes:channels length:data.length];
```

Comment: Why do you need it written in Objective-C? An alternative would be to keep the code in Swift and call it from Objectice-c via a method.

Comment: I'm working on a project and converted all swift code to objective c Except for these two codes!!

Comment: Have you at least tried to converted them? If yes, please share with us the attempts and the problems you ran into. If not, please note SO is not a translation service.

Comment: @ehsan not sure but something like this way you can write... `[data getBytes:channels[0] length:data.length];`
    `AVAudioPCMBuffer *readBuffer = [[AvAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat: audioFormat frameCapacity: kBufferFrameCapacity];`

Comment: @Cristik edited question...

Comment: @ehsan Why would you convert Swift code to Obj-C? Why not converting everything the Swift?

Comment: @Sulthan because I need to implement this code in an objective c big project.

Comment: @ehsan, have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What the original code does is copying the parameter `data` into `PCMBuffer.floatChannelData`.

What your code does is creating a new byte buffer, then copying that empty buffer to `PCMBuffer` and copying parameter data into the buffer.

I believe it should be just something similar to:

```
PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity;
[data getBytes:PCMBuffer.floatChannelData length:data.length];
return PCMBuffer;
```

Comment: @ehsan Could you please be more specific?

Comment: `Sending 'float *const  _Nonnull * _Nullable' to parameter of type 'void * _Nonnull' discards qualifiers`